# Lun storage vmfs6 to vmfs5 issue

Tags: vmfs

We have a new environment containing 6 Esxi hosts, and we need to change the LUN format from VMFS6 to VMFS5.

there's no data on the servers, so what is the correct process?

Dismount the LUN (VMFS6) and creating a new one using VMFS5 format, or deleting the datastore and creating a new one?

(I know for the Netapp guys it's an easy question, i just want to do this thing right and learn the difference between the dismounting or deleting a lun i have in the esxi).

Thank you all,

I didn't took any step in order to learn how to do this process right.

Answer (score 1):

VMFS version refers to the datastore.  It is not necessary to modify the LUN.

Using an analogy, a LUN is like a physical hard disk, and a datastore is like a partition on a disk.  You want to remove an NTFS partition to make room for a FAT32 partition.

Steps

1. Unmount the datastore from each esxi host
2. Delete the datastore
3. Create a new datastore of the desired VMFS version.
4. Trigger a storage rescan on each host.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2147824
(Starting at step 7 because there's no VMs or data)

It's customary to choose newer formats, when possible.